# How to detect a div over another div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to detect a div over another div with jQuery? any solution?? thanks for you answer

Comment: What do you have? What have you tried? Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) selector. Note it travels only a single level down the dom for anything else use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
<div class="abc">

  <div class="def">Div 2</div>
  <div class="def">Div 3</div>

</div>
```

Somehow find the parent div.. using a class or id selector or choosing it smarlty by using first. last etc.

```
$(".abc").children().each(function(){
$(this).html("test");
});
```

or use a selector

```
$(".abc").children(":first").append("test2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fVQB8/
Does that help you?

Comment: Pretty sure the OP means overlap, not distinguish

Comment: Thanks! but i meant a div under another div because i will make a game so my "actors" should run on the background and not collide

Answer (score 0):

To get this you can use the following code, if your one DIV is called i1 and the other div is called example Image1 - then you can get the offsetTop and offsetLeft positions and compare them.

```
    var y = document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
    var x = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;


    var elementy = document.getElementById('image1').offsetTop;
    var elementx = document.getElementById('image1').offsetLeft;

    if (elementy == y) {
        if (elementx == x) {
            gameover();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this or use `$('#div').on('dragstart',function(evt)`

```
var CardOnePosistion;
var MovedPosition;
        
$(function(){     
MovedPosition = $('#Moved').position();
CardOne = $('#CardOne').position();
 if (MovedPosition.left === CardOne.left && MovedPosition.top === CardOne.top) {
       alert("Div over another Div");
  } 
}
```